# Problem with Microsoft login for Office 365 account via Firebase Auth in web when user is created with NodeJS Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I noticed a strange issue with Microsoft login for firebase web. In our app's workflow, when a user is invited, we create a user using NodeJS Admin SDK using code similar to this:-

```
await admin.auth().createUser({
    displayName,
    email,
    emailVerified: true
});
```

I tested this approach by logging into my app with a Hotmail account and that worked as expected. However, when I asked someone to try this with a Microsoft Office 365 account, it failed with the following error:-

> An account already exists with the same email address but different
> sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this
> email address

This error message is not correct because this user has never logged in before and in firebase console, I see no providers associated with this user as can be seen from this image.

[image: No providers in firebase auth]

Why is Microsoft Office 365 login via firebase auth (web) failing for this user?

Comment: I really think that this issue needs to be verified by the [Firebase team](https://firebase.google.com/support) since they can test this scenario and provide you further advice.